# PowerShell - Eliminar Directorios manteniendo los ultimos x creados

Tags: powershell

Necesito eliminar directorios, el problema es que hay directorios con diferente nombres y de cada uno ocupo mantener los ultimos 2 creados.

**Ejemplo:** Mantener *Folder_4, Folder_3, Test_4, Test_3* del siguiente path:

```
Directory: C:\Users\ad_karendex\Documents\TEST


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                      
d----         5/15/2017   2:42 PM            Folder_1                                                                                                                                  
d----         5/15/2017   2:42 PM            Folder_2                                                                  
d----         5/15/2017   2:42 PM            Folder_3                                                                  
d----         5/15/2017   2:42 PM            Folder_4                                                                                                                               
d----         5/15/2017   2:43 PM            Test_1                                                                                                                                     
d----         5/15/2017   2:43 PM            Test_2                                                                    
d----         5/15/2017   2:43 PM            Test_3                                                                    
d----         5/15/2017   2:43 PM            Test_4
```

He logrado agrupar ambos directorios para luego poder borrar por grupo, pero no he logrado eliminar los directorios  obsoletos.

Agrupar:

```
$path = "C:\Users\ad_karendex\Documents\TEST"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer}  | Group-Object { $_.Name.Split('_')[0] }
```

Necesito algo similar a esto para removerlos manteniendo los 2 nuevas versiones:

```
$keep = 2
if ($files.Count -gt $keep) {
    $files | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First ($files.Count - $keep) | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -WhatIf}
```

Cualquier ayuda sería de gran ayuda...pero tomen please en cuenta que apenas estoy iniciando con PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind! ya lo pude solucionar :

```
gci "C:\Users\ad_karendex\Documents\TEST" -Recurse | 
where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer} |
Group-Object {$_.Name.Split('_')[0] } |
foreach {
  $_.Group |
  sort CreationTime -Descending |
  Select -Skip 2 |
   foreach { Remove-Item $_.fullname -Force }
  }
```